# При использовании pyrebase на macos получаю ошибку

Tags: python, firebase

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyrebase

  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrebase/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/parser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Что делать кто знает?

Ответ:
Установить pyrebase4

Comment: Вообще ошибка у вас в модуле `requests`. Попробуйте его обновить. У вас версия `requests` для питона младше `3.10`, в которой `MutableMapping` переехал в `collections.abc`. Ну либо можете по-быстрому поменять в `cookies.py` строку `collections.MutableMapping` на `collections.abc.MutableMapping`

Comment: Ответ должен быть в ответах, а не в самом вопросе.

Comment: @insolor Да как-то непонятно ответ это или что. Может копипаста.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался. Все работает! Адаптируюсь под python после java